# how to avoid my events to acumulate on javascript (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

look at this image the "recibido" (received) message is suposed to log only once per call, I have hours trying to figure out why it acumulates.

[image: events]

this is the code:

module Serial.js

```
var Promise=require('bluebird');
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var openedPort=false;
var puerto;



var Serial = function(port) {
  puerto = port;
this.serialPort = new SerialPort(puerto, { //crea un objeto serialport, abre el puerto
baudrate: 9600
});

this.serialPort.on("open", function () { //cuando se abra el puerto...
console.log('\n\nPUERTO '+ puerto+ ' ABIERTO\n\n');
openedPort=true;    
});




this.send = function (d){

    var p = "\x02"+d+"\x0D";//agrega STX y ETX
    var prom = new Promise.defer();
    var timeout;

       this.serialPort.on('data', function (data) {


                console.log('RECIBIDO: '+ data );
                data=''+data;
                //clearTimeout(timeout);//no hace falta, la promesa solo se resuelve una  vez
                prom.resolve(data.trim())
           });  

        console.log("ENVIANDO: "+p+'');+
        this.serialPort.write(p, function (err, results) {
            if (err) prom.reject(new Error(err))
            })
        timeout=setTimeout(function(){
            //console.log('AGOTADO'.blue)               
            prom.reject(new Error('Tiempo agotado al enviar paquete, No hubo respuesta'.red))
        },500);
    return prom.promise;
}
return this;
}
module.exports = Serial;
```

and the app.js:

```
var serial = require('./Serial.js');
var s = new serial('COM1');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var colors = require('colors');
//console.log(s)
dec ='KH970DMQDSD';
s.serialPort.on('open',function(){
console.log('ACTIVANDO DECO:'.cyan+dec);
habilitar(dec).then(function(d){return refrescar(d)}).then(function(d){return                 habilitar(d)}).then(function(d){return refrescar(d)}).then(function (d) {

console.log('ACTIVADO'.cyan+d)
}


, function(e){
console.log('viene de serial '+e)})
});




function habilitar(d){
console.log('\n\nHABILITANDO'.green);
var deco=d; 
return s.send("06"+d)
.then(function  (d) {
    //console.log('realizado\n');
    //console.log('datos: '+d+' len: '+d.length);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    d = d.substr(1,d.length-1);
    //console.log('recibo: '+d+',');
    if(d!="00"){
        reject(new Error ('El comando devolvio error\n'.red+d))
    }
    else{
    console.log('HABILITADO DATA: '.green+d);
   // console.log(s.serialPort.path)
    resolve(deco)
        }
})
 })
 }
function refrescar(d){
console.log('\n\nREFRESCANDO'.green);
var deco=d;
return s.send("04"+d)
.then(function  (d) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    //console.log('realizado\n');
    //console.log('datos: '+d+' len: '+d.length);
    d = d.substr(1,d.length-1);
    //console.log('recibo: '+d+',');
    if(d!="00"){
        reject(new Error ('El comando refrescar ha devuelto error\n'.red+d))
    }
    else{
    console.log('REFRESCADO DATA: '.green+d);
   // console.log(s.serialPort.path)
    resolve(deco,d)
        }
})
})
}
```

I don't really know if I am using those events bad, or what I really am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding to the `data` event on the port every time you send something.  That is, the following block of code:

```
this.serialPort.on('data', function (data) {


            console.log('RECIBIDO: '+ data );
            data=''+data;
            //clearTimeout(timeout);//no hace falta, la promesa solo se resuelve una  vez
            prom.resolve(data.trim())
       });
```

is inside your `send` method.  This means that every time you call `send`, another event handler is attached, and each time there's a `data` event, every one of those handlers is called.  You either need to bind to the `data` event outside of the `send` method, or use `once` instead of `on`, which causes the handler to be removed after one call.  Which you use depends on how exactly you need it to behave.